# Error in rosdep init

Tags: init

I have Elementary OS and a try install ROS (Robot Operating System) and when i try initialization `sudo rosdep init` i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 3, in <module>
from rosdep2.main import rosdep_main
ImportError: No module named 'rosdep2'
```

I don't know what's the problem... thanks all!

Answer (score -1):

Executing this command resolved the problem for me:

```
sudo -H pip install -U rosdep
```

This should install the missing Python module.